# What array character comes first in a php string?

Tags: php

Hi I would like to get the position strpos() and the first upcoming character in a php string. How can I do that?

Here would be an example:

```
$searchingCharacter = ['a', 'u', 'e'];
$LoockForCharacterInThisString = "butterly";
```

The output should be:
The first character is "u" at position # 2

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This site should not be a place for plain "how to" (a.k.a. "make for me") questions. Have you tried anything yet? Then please show it, together with a proper problem description, if it did not work. If you have not tried anything yet - then what has your _research_ turned up so far at least?

Comment: @Geoffrey thanks I tried to explain it better. However I do not know how to code this. Otherwise I would not have asked. Maybe I could code it in a really long way.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```php
<?php

$searchingCharacter = ['a', 'u', 'e'];
$lookForCharacterInThisString = "butterly";

/**
 * This will return the index of the haystack where the first needle in the haystack was found.
 * If nothing was found, null will be returned.
 */
function firstIndex(string $haystack, array $needles): ?int
{
    $needleIndexes = array_filter(
        array_map(fn($needle) => strpos($haystack, $needle), $needles),
        fn($position) => $position !== false
    );

    return count($needleIndexes) > 0 ? min($needleIndexes) : null;
}

$firstIndex = firstIndex($lookForCharacterInThisString, $searchingCharacter);
echo $firstIndex === null 
    ? 'None of the characters were found'
    : 'The first character is "'.$lookForCharacterInThisString[$firstIndex].'" at position # '.($firstIndex+1);
```

Inside the firstIndex, I used `array_map` to search for the position of the needle for all possible needles. Next, I filter out any needles that were not found using `array_filter` and finally I return the minimum position if any of the needles were found or `NULL` if none were found.

The output of this function can be used to generate the output. This [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/6j2DE) can be checked for a working example.